# website returning random 504 and 502 errors

Tags: 500-internal-error, troubleshooting

I am getting 502/ 504 errors on the website randomly, and have tried all the methods to debug the issue but unable to fix it
When getting 5xx errors, I tried renaming the plugins folder to check if website is loading, and is loading. Then I tried installing each plugin one by one to find the faulty plugin but unable to find any issue as all plugins are being installed successfully but after some time it is throwing 5xx errors.
I tried keeping logs for but none are being inserted in the debug.log too !
Any any one please guide on how to troubleshoot the issue ?

Comment: 502 and 504 are gateway errors, and I'm reasonably sure WordPress does not generate them itself. It sounds like you've got a reverse proxy in front of your site, and that's what's generating these errors (although possibly because your web server isn't accepting its requests). Can you find the gateway / reverse proxy and look at logs on that? Is your web server overloaded to the point it would drop connections? I'd talk to your host if you haven't already too.

Comment: @Rup we are aws beanstalk env for hosting, we haven't used any reverse proxy. We have checked the max amount of connections which is in normal state.